# How do I enable Apollo Tracing with Hot Chocolate for all query requests permanently?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

When using [Hot Chocolate](https://hotchocolate.io) with *.Net Core* I am creating my scheme like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Here I register my services / repositories; omitted for brevity

        services.AddGraphQL(sp => Schema.Create(c =>
        {
            // Here I register my schema types and so on; omitted for brevity
        }));
    }

     // Code omitted for brevity
}
```

But how do I enable the built-in *Apollo Tracing* for all requests actually? And does it work with *.Net Framework* the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, by setting the `TracingPreference` option to `TracingPreference.Always`.

The following code fragment shows how this would look like.

```
services.AddGraphQL(sp => Schema.Create(c =>
{
    // Here goes the schema definition which is omitted for brevity purpose
}),
new QueryExecutionOptions
{
    TracingPreference = TracingPreference.Always
});
```

And yes, it works the same way in .Net Framework. The API in .Net Core and Framework is kept identical let say 99% identical. What here differs is just the surrounding which means the Startup class which wraps the DI configuration.

For more information about *Apollo Tracing*, head over [here](https://hotchocolate.io/docs/apollo-tracing).